# How to activate Autodesk Forge Snapper?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, viewer

I'm trying to activate the new Snapper extension implemented since version 7.3 of the viewer.

So I load the extension like that :

`viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.Snapping')`

Seems to work.
And after, I tried to access described methods like that but I always got this error " getSnapResult is not a function" :

```
viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.Snapping').then(extension =>{
    snapper = extension;
});

snapper.getSnapResult();
```

I'm still using the old extension made by Philippe Leefsma a few years ago :
https://forge.autodesk.com/cloud_and_mobile/2015/09/geometry-snapping-and-selection-commands-with-view-data-api.html

But as it's not working anymore in version up to 7.3, I would like to replace with the new one.

Comment: Hi Alex, checking with our Viewer team now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getSnapResult() is a function within the Snapper class. Here is a link to the documentation:

https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Snapping/Snapper/

And you can try the following:

```
var snapper = new Autodesk.Viewing.Extensions.Snapping.Snapper();
//...
snapper.getSnapResult();
```

Comment: Thank you Jaime. I tried that but I get this error : ```TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'e.globalManager') x - Snapper.js: 216```

Comment: Ok, the previous error was because I didn't pass the viewer to the constructor. It's working with something like that : ```var snapper = new Autodesk.Viewing.Extensions.Snapping.Snapper(viewer, {});```