# How to use Forge Viewer Snapper?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

I'm trying to use Snapper functionnalities from Forge Viewer in order to ask user to pick a point and then retrieve point world coordinates of selected point.

I look at this topic but doesn't work for me : [How to activate Autodesk Forge Snapper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58487001/how-to-activate-autodesk-forge-snapper)

I load the extension like that :
`this.viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.Snapping');`

And then try to use the Snapper like that:

```
               console.log(this._viewer.toolController.getActiveToolName());
               var snapper = new Autodesk.Viewing.Extensions.Snapping.Snapper(this._viewer, {});

               this._viewer.toolController.registerTool(snapper);
               this._viewer.toolController.activateTool('snapper');

               console.log(this._viewer.toolController.getToolNames());
               console.log(this._viewer.toolController.getActiveToolName());

               var a = snapper.getSnapResult();
               console.log(a);
```

In the log the snapper is activated but i am enable to pick a point in viewer ann to get results with getSnapResult function.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Detailed Example can be found here: [Snappy Viewer Tools](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/snappy-viewer-tools)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The snapper tool works with both 2d and 3d models and you will need to provide a hit test result that is tested positive by e.g. a click on the canvas, so say:

```
const snapper = new Autodesk.Viewing.Extensions.Snapping.Snapper(NOP_VIEWER)
const hitTestResult = NOP_VIEWER.impl.snappingHitTest(clickEvent.x, clickEvent.y)
snapper.snapping3D(hitTestResult)
snapper.getSnapResult()
```

You may subscribe to canvas click events with your custom tool - see [here](https://jsbin.com/kipagaf/14/edit) for details.