# BBoxes not optimal - Recalculating Bounding Boxes in Autodesk Forge Viewer

Tags: three.js, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

There are several models in which the bounding boxes look something like this:

[Three slabs with their bounding box drawn in.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5PJc.png)

1. Slab: bbox fits perfectly
2. Slab: bbox makes sense as well
3. Slab: bbox has same orientation as the other two, but is far bigger than necessary

The multiselect function I'm using uses the vertices of the element's boundingboxes to make it faster.

My question in that regard is wether it's possible to recalculate those bounding boxes to fit better or if this will possibly improve in a future update.

Comment: In short; no, probably not. The bounding boxes in the image look to be a perfect fit, they are the smallest they can be while covering the whole geometry. Even the third. I do understand what you mean, it's a bit weird, bounding boxes are always aligned with world axis, but that's how they are supposed to work.

Comment: [See the docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/helpers/BoxHelper) for a description on how a bounding box behaves. As Ethan said, they "graphically show the world-axis-aligned bounding box around an object", which means they enclose the volume between the minimum x, y, z values to the maximum x, y, z values. They don't rotate with your object.

Comment: Just my humble two cents adding to the insightful comments above I assume you've employed a mechanism similar to this [extension](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-rcdb.nodejs/tree/master/src/client/components/Viewer/Extensions/Dynamic/Viewing.Extension.SelectionWindow) so what you've achieved is probably as far as we could get so maybe try something else for example the [snapper tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60400113/how-to-use-forge-viewer-snapper) to test if the selected boundaries could snap onto the edges of the components? Just a thought and feel free to add ...

Comment: @EthanHermsey I see - I assumed the bounding boxes could be orientated to fit optimal, turns out it is more complicated as it sounds

I wanted to use the bounding box geometry for geometry intersection to make it easier for me, but seems like I will need to use the actual geometry instead of the box.
Thank you!

Comment: @Marquizzo thank you - I will have to use another method

Comment: @BryanHuang correct :) four planes and determining whether the bounding box vertices are in/out.
Cool idea, I played around and got some snapping3D results - but I think I'd have to rewrite the tool a bit to work with planes instead of rays and a large detection radius.
The last code samples I found are 5 years old, do you happen to know where I might find an up to date one?

Comment: @EthanHermsey I think this is in short the 100% correct answer as you put it -> could you post it as an answer?

Comment: I will add @BryanHuang approach & results in an edit.