# Is there any way to snap the model point of the Viewer?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I try to get and snap the model point in the viewer that like the function of the measure distance tool of the viewer tool bar.

I have got the point by mouseclick event . Is there any way to have the snap function in the viewer?

```
    let pt = viewer.impl.hitTest(
      event.clientX,
      event.clientY,
      true,
      null,
      [mModel.getModelId()]
    );
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **measure** extension use another extension called `Autodesk.Snapping`. You can use this extension to *snap* vertices, edges or faces.

Here's another question with a short example on [how to use the forge viewer snapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60400113/how-to-use-forge-viewer-snapper).

And you can read this great article about the **snapping extension** : [Snappy viewer tools](https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/snappy-viewer-tools)