# Show icon snap on Forge Viewer 3D

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I try to show snap icon (*some yellow icon go with cursor appear when make measurement*) when the cursor hover on the 3d model. This is my function and it not work for me at all. Do i miss some thing ?

```
onMouseMove = (event) => {
  const snapper = new Autodesk.Viewing.Extensions.Snapping.Snapper(this.viewer);
  const worldCoordinate = this.viewer.impl.hitTest(event.clientX, event.clientY);

  if (worldCoordinate === null) return;
  const hitTestResult = this.viewer.impl.snappingHitTest(
    worldCoordinate.x,
    worldCoordinate.y,
    worldCoordinate.z
  );
  if (hitTestResult === null) return;
  snapper.snapping3D(hitTestResult);
  const result = snapper.getSnapResult();
}
```

I'm also reference some of these topic but not work for me. [How to use Forge Viewer Snapper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60400113/how-to-use-forge-viewer-snapper)
[How to activate Autodesk Forge Snapper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58487001/how-to-activate-autodesk-forge-snapper)
https://autodeskviewer.com/viewers/latest/docs/extensions_Measure_Measure.js.html
. Thank in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think this issue is caused from the missing of container offset of the viewer. The world coordinates cannot be tested correctly. Please check the code below if it helps.
If I misunderstood the question,could you share a bit more information on what it is not working?

**UPDATE**:

```
onMouseMove = (event) => {

  const snapper = new Autodesk.Viewing.Extensions.Snapping.Snapper(this.viewer);

  const viewer_pos = this.viewer.container.getBoundingClientRect();   

  const worldCoordinate = this.viewer.impl.hitTest(event.clientX-viewer_pos.x, event.clientY-viewer_pos.y); 
 if (worldCoordinate === null) return;

 // const hitTestResult = this.viewer.impl.snappingHitTest(
 //   worldCoordinate.point.x,
 //   worldCoordinate.point.y,
 //   worldCoordinate.point.z
 // );    
 //if (hitTestResult === null) return;

 snapper.snapping3D(worldCoordinate);
 const result = snapper.getSnapResult(); 
 snapper.indicator.render()
 }
```

Comment: Hi Xiaodong, i want to show the snap mark like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2dzC.png) when my mouse hover over the model. I try to test with your new suggestion but not work for me too.

Comment: Hi Trung, just now, I did not check why snappingHitTest is required. And worldCoordinate does not have x,y,z, while worldCoordinate.point has. I guess these code are come from the old version of Viewer. So I checked the code of Measurement Extension of latest version (v7.23). I think the data from hitTest is enough which tells the geometry and intersect point. by these, snapper will calculate the points and render the indicator. I updated the code and uploaded a test video on how it is working  at my side: https://youtu.be/iDd9E2SBVe0